# Owl universal quantification works together with cardinality restrictions

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I am new to owl. I read an Universal Quantification example in this page http://dior.ics.muni.cz/~makub/owl/ .

If I replace "Person SubClassOf hasParent max 2 thing" by "Person SubClassOf hasParent max 2 Person" and run the reasoner, I think individual Ivan would fall into the class Czech too. But actually it's not. I test it in Protege 4.3 and run the built-in reasoner FaCT++.

What details did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here that your new restriction is too permissive. Your new axiom actually say that Person can have at most 2 (parents that are Person). It doesn't prevent Person from having other parents, that are non-Person.

The example will work again if you enforce all parents to be of a class Person, e.g by setting Range of hasParent to Person, or adding an axiom `Person SubClassOf hasParent only Person`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and solution, I did't fully take into account open world assumption.